# PXE booting through a network in VMWare

Tags: fedora, pxe

I am trying to set up a PXE server which serves as a DHCP client too. I am testing this in VMWare on Fedora 25.

I have two Network Adapters configured. One is NAT'ed and the other is a custom VMnet to which the PXE client will connect. My client boots into the boot menu and loads the initrd image. But when it wants to start downloading the client can't resolve the image domain.

How can I make the custom VMnet use the NAT connection so the image can be downloaded?

this is my dhcpd.conf

```
option arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
if option arch = 00:07 {
filename "uefi/shim.efi";
} else {
filename "pxelinux.0";
}

authoritative;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;

range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254;

option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
option routers 192.168.1.1;

}
```

Comment: What does it want to download from where? What is the "image domain" (can the name be resolved by 8.8.8.8)? Is IP forwarding enabled in your PXE server to forward traffic from the "custom VMnet" to the"NATed VMnet"?

Comment: I've never netbooted an Intel-compatible, but when netbooting my SPARC machine, I have to provide a `next-server` line in `dhcpd.conf`, else it tries to load from the DHCP server rather than the one that holds the boot image

Comment: @ridgy The image domain is a publicly accessible VPS which can be resolved by 8.8.8.8. I do not know how to forward the traffic with ip forwarding exactly. I have enabled the forwarding. But it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Fox My DHCP server is also my PXE server. I am trying to boot a live image so in my default pxelinux file i point to root=live:[http://image]. Do I have to specify the image holding server as my next-server?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the next-server option had to be set. I assumed, as I was running my PXE server with initrd.img and vmlinuz files on the same server as the DHCP, that this server had no next-server. But DHCP needed the ip in my case.